# Как получить ArrayList<Object> с JSON с помощью Retrofit 2.1.0?

Tags: android, retrofit

Пытаюсь разобраться, как парсить JSON с помощью Retrofit 2.1, и получить на выходе массив с объектами `Manager`

Создал запрос в интерфейсе, в `MainActivity` инициализировал сам `Retrofit`

**[JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/xkyz)-файл:**

```
   {
  "managers": 
[

    {"name": "John Smith", "plan": "100"},
    {"name": "Alex Sprite", "plan": "96"},
    {"name": "Den Bollom", "plan": "2"},
    {"name": "Jaromir Jagr", "plan": "68"},
    {"name": "Wane Gretzky", "plan": "99"},
    {"name": "Winsent Trade", "plan": "54"},
    {"name": "Paul Dagger", "plan": "30"},
    {"name": "Tommy Gun", "plan": "60"},
    {"name": "Luc Perry", "plan": "15"},
    {"name": "Tend Smarr", "plan": "64"}


   ] 

  }
```

**ManagerApi**

```
public interface ManagerAPI {


    String URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/";



    @GET("xkyz.json")
    Call<Manager> getManagers();


}
```

**Метод инициализации Retrofit**

```
 private void requestData() {


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ManagerAPI.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ManagerAPI service = retrofit.create(ManagerAPI.class);

    }
```

Так же есть класс `Manager`, со всеми нужными гетерами. Не могу понять, что в данном случае делать дальше.

Comment: Эмм... `service.getManagers();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, необходимо отформатировать JSON:

```
[

    {"name": "John Smith", "plan": "100"},
    {"name": "Alex Sprite", "plan": "96"},
    {"name": "Den Bollom", "plan": "2"},
    {"name": "Jaromir Jagr", "plan": "68"},
    {"name": "Wane Gretzky", "plan": "99"},
    {"name": "Winsent Trade", "plan": "54"},
    {"name": "Paul Dagger", "plan": "30"},
    {"name": "Tommy Gun", "plan": "60"},
    {"name": "Luc Perry", "plan": "15"},
    {"name": "Tend Smarr", "plan": "64"}


   ]
```

Реализация **requestData**:

```
 private void requestData() {

        Retrofit retrofit = getRetrofit();
        ManagerAPI service = retrofit.create(ManagerAPI.class);
        Call<List<Manager>> call = service.getManagers();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Manager>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Manager>> call, Response<List<Manager>> response) {

                Log.e("OnResponce", "OK");


                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    List<Manager> managers = response.body();
                    tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    tw.setText(String.valueOf(managers.get(0).getName() + " "+ managers.get(0).getPlan()));

                    System.out.println(managers.toString());

                }
                else {
                    Log.e("Response Successful?", "NO");
                    Log.e("response.message",response.message());
                    Log.e("response.code", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    Log.e("response.body", String.valueOf(response.body()));



                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Manager>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("OnFailure", "Fail");
                Log.e((t.getMessage()), t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    private Retrofit getRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ManagerAPI.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
```

`call` создаёт новый запрос, далее он запускается в новом асинхронном потоке. (`enqueue`, если дословно - добавить в конец очереди).
Если запрос успешен - данные можно получить из `response.body()`;